# Hiking trail algorithm

Tags: arrays, matrix, graph-algorithm

The input is a 2-dimensional array `A[n][n]` of numbers representing the topographic map of a geographic surface. Each number represents the area's elevation. Input will be a starting location `(r,c)`, referring to entry `A[r][c]`.

A person could traverse between two adjacent locations if their elevations differ by no more than 2. Adjacency follows just the 4 standard compass
directions (no diagonals). A point on the map is considered reachable if it is traversable from `A[r][c]` through any sequence of adjacent entries.

I have to write an algorithm that computes all of the reachable locations in the grid. The output will be another 2-D array `R[n][n]` with true/false values. True means reachable, false means unreachable.

Sample: Suppose `A[10][10]` looks like this, for starting location `A[0][0]`:

```
50 51 54 58 60 60 60 63 68 71
48 52 51 59 60 60 63 63 69 70
44 48 52 55 58 61 64 64 66 69
44 46 53 52 57 60 60 61 65 68
42 45 50 54 59 61 63 63 66 70
38 42 46 56 56 63 64 61 64 62
36 40 44 50 58 60 66 65 62 61
36 39 42 49 56 62 67 66 65 60
30 36 40 47 50 64 64 63 62 60
50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50
```

The corresponding output array should be:

```
1  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
1  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  0  0
0  0  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  0
0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  0
0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  1  0
0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  1
0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  1
0  0  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  1
0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I'm not sure how I even start this. Can someone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: The input is a random every time though.

Comment: I assume this is a homework question. What graph algorithms have you learned in class so far?

Comment: @ndmeiri Yes it is. The only one I can think of that was close to this was a question asking to output all saddle points in a random matrix. A saddle point is where a value is the least in its row, and greatest in its column, and vice versa.

Comment: Try representing your map as a graph. When should two positions be connected? Do you know any algorithms that could give you all accessible positions starting from a certain node in a graph?

Comment: @TobiasRibizel I know practically nothing when it comes to graphing algorithms. I've only done one question that was close to this, and it seemed much easier.

Comment: This is like lattice Boltzmann method for discretizing sloped surface kind of. Are there limits on its run time? Divide and conquer.

Comment: Okay, then you can also approach this problems without thinking about Graphs at all. Maybe think about it this way: You start from a certain position. You want to visit all of its reachable neighbors, so remember these neighbors (store them in some way) and mark the start position as visited. Then take the first neighbor you remembered and do the same thing (however be careful not to visit positions you already visited before.